# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, anaconda

I am getting an issue in creating a CSV file from my database. Below is my code.

```
import pymysql  
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import time
import json
# open connection to the database  
conn = pymysql.connect(host='your host',  
                       port=3306,  
                       user='user_name',  
                       passwd='',  
                       db='ai_demo',  
                       charset='utf8')  
cur = conn.cursor()  

sql = "SELECT order_data FROM `transactions`" 
cur.execute(sql) 
rows = cur.fetchall()
data = {}
dadaArray=[]
for row in rows:
    #print(row)
    for i in row:
         s=json.loads(i)
    for item in s:
        date_str = item.get('date')
        date_object = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
        #print(date_object)
        time_str = item.get('time')
        time_object = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M:%S').time()
        print(time_object)
        date_time_object = datetime.combine(date_object,time_object)
        #print(date_time_object)
        subscription_price = item.get('totalOrderSubscriptionPrice')
        data['timestamp'] =date_time_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        data['price'] = json.loads(subscription_price)
        #print(data)
        dadaArray.append(data)


#with open("out.csv", "w", newline='') as csv_file:  # Python 3 version    
with open("out.csv", "wb") as csv_file:              # Python 2 version
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow([data for data in dadaArray]) # write headers
    csv_writer.writerows(cur)
# close connection to the database  
cur.close()  
conn.close()
```

The problem is that I am getting some values correctly but after some time it starts giving error **" AttributeError: 'Unicode' object has no attribute 'get'"**

**Here is the full console of my spyder**:

```
runfile('/Users/mss/.spyder/temp.py', wdir='/Users/mss/.spyder')
06:29:58
06:30:05
06:30:11
06:30:23
06:36:48
06:38:57
06:46:41
07:15:32
07:51:57
07:52:02
07:51:57
07:52:02
08:52:40
08:52:50
08:52:55
08:52:40
08:52:50
08:52:55
08:52:40
08:52:50
08:52:55
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-b3aa9a745687>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/mss/.spyder/temp.py', wdir='/Users/mss/.spyder')

  File "/Users/mss/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/mss/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/Users/mss/.spyder/temp.py", line 28, in <module>
    date_str = item.get('date')

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I am not sure that why it halts in between as it was initially providing me dates but after some looping, it halts and starts saying "Unicode' object has no attribute 'get".But as you can see it has printed some dates before displaying this error.

This is what my **item** looks like for (for item in s:):

```
{u'delivered': u'yes', u'versionCode': u'2.2', u'date': u'2019-09-08', u'containerGiven': u'0', u'items': [{u'unit_name': u'ML', u'pricr_per_package': 19, u'name': u'NANDINI TONED', u'containerGiven': u'0', u'sub_id': 299, u'quantity_child': 1, u'containerCollect': u'0', u'modify_data': 0, u'pro_price': 0, u'child_package_qty': 500, u'type': u'subscription', u'id': 578, u'quantity': 1}], u'totalOrderSubscriptionPrice': u'19.0', u'userId': u'989', u'containerCollect': u'0', u'time': u'06:29:58', u'custom_ids': u'[]', u'schdule_id': 54, u'subscription_ids': u'[299]'}
```

I may look silly. But the point is I am very new to Python. Please let me know the reason why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: is your indentation correct with those two for-loops? when you do `for i in row: s=json.loads(i)` you just reset the value of `s` each loop before moving on, and then to follow up if `s` is a JSON blob you can't iterate over it since you are just iterating over keys in a dictionary which are just strings so they do not have a `get` method

Comment: @aws_apprentice, Thank you for your reply mate. Can you please explain that with code example. That would be more helpful in understanding.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two issues I can see with the code, the first issue is:

```
for i in row:
    s=json.loads(i)
```

If `row` is `n` items long then you are essentially discarding every value that isn't the last item, `n`. The reason for this is because your next for-loop is indented on the same level as this loop.

The second issue is:

```
for item in s:
    date_str = item.get('date')
```

Since we know `s` is a JSON blob (essentially a dictionary) we can not iterate over it the same way we would a list, since we are just iterating over the *keys* in the dictionary. It seems like you want your code to look like the following:

```
for i in row:
    s = json.loads(i)
    date_str = s.get('date')
    date_object = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    #print(date_object)
    time_str = s.get('time')
    ...
```

You only really need one for-loop here based on the data you have shown.